# Boostrap carousel page indicator wrongly align

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My page indicator for boostrap carousel went to the middle of the div container. I have no idea why. I had follow all the code from w3schools, it is the padding problem?? Anyone know how to solve it, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    .bg-1 { 
      background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .bg-2 { 
      background-color: #f6f6f6; /* Grey */
      color: black;
    }

    .bg-3 { 
      background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    /*.container{
        padding-top: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 200px;

    }*/

    .footer-size{
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        padding-left: 50px;
        padding-right: 50px;


    }

    .navbar {
      padding-top: 8px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
        max-width: 1000px;
        padding-top: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 200px;
        }

    }



     @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container-fluid{
        max-width: 970px;
        }
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- NavBar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Product</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Product 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Product 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Product 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<br><br><br>


<!-- Container-->



<div class="container bg-1 text-center">
<br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators for carousel-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>


        <!-- Wrapper for Slide -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <h3 class="margin">Carousel</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <h3 class="margin">Carousel 2</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>


<div class="container bg-2 text-center">
    <h4 class="margin">Example</h3>
</div>

<div class="container bg-3 text-center">
    <h5 class="margin">Example</h3>

</div>

<footer class="footer-size text-center">
    <a href=""></a>
    <p>
Copyright 2017 Example | All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your slides for your carousel only contains the text "Carousel" and "Carousel 2" and not the background. So, the height of the carousel is only the text's height, and not the background's.

Try this:

```
.container{
        max-width: 1000px;
        /*remove your padding*/
        }
    #myCarousel {
        height:500px /*give a specific height*/
        /* If you put images into your carousel slide, you don't have to add
        this as the carousel will take the size of the images*/
    }
```

And this is your markup

```
    <div class="container text-center">
<br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide bg-1" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators for carousel-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>


        <!-- Wrapper for Slide -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <h3 class="margin">Carousel</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <h3 class="margin">Carousel 2</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add this style

```
  .carousel-indicators { top:230px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have used text content inside Item List...

If you want only text content to scroll, then give it some appropriate size to fill the width of your container.

Comment: Thx, finally I know what's happen, you let me know the logic of carousel